# How to disable title&content in semantic-ui accordion?

Tags: jquery, semantic-ui

It would be great if I could enable/disable an accordion item by class in semantic-ui by simply adding and removing the 'disabled' class. (like with buttons and inputs)

1) Are there plans on integrating this functionality in the future?
2) Can someone provide a workaround that accomplishes this?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I decided to just create my own custom class for now that borrows from the button element.

```
.disabled.title {
  cursor: default;
  background-color: #dcddde !important;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) !important;
  opacity: 0.3 !important;
  background-image: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

I can then do:

```
<div class="ui accordion">
    <div class="disabled title">
      title
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```